# pySpark.sql how to use WHERE keyword?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How do you use `WHERE` keyword to get the count of gender and their percentage, who survived in titanic disaster?

my code:

```python
spark.sql(
    "SELECT Sex Where Survived=1 ,count(Sex) \
    as gender_count,count(sex)*100/sum(count(sex)) over() \
    as percent from titanic_table GROUP BY sex"
).show()
```

error:

> ```python
> ParseException: "
> mismatched input ',' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 28)
> == SQL ==
> SELECT Sex Where Survived=1 ,count(Sex) 
> as gender_count,count(sex)*100/sum(count(sex)) over() 
> as percent from titanic_table GROUP BY sex
> ----------------------------^^^
> "
> ```

Comment: You syntax is incorrect. You can't use `WHERE` in the `SELECT` expression like that. It has to come after the `FROM`. In this case, it looks like you also you need to use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: may i know how the syntax would be like?

Comment: Generally the form needs to be `SELECT <columns>, <aggregations> FROM table WHERE <conditions> GROUP BY <columns>`. For a more specific explanation, please [edit] your question to include a small, self contained [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples) with the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put it after `FROM` and before `GROUP BY`.

Your code should be :

```py
spark.sql("SELECT Sex, count(Sex) AS gender_count, \
100*count(sex)/sum(count(sex)) over() AS percent \
FROM titanic_table \
WHERE Survived = 1 \
GROUP BY sex").show()
```